# Want to double check if my T-Sql update Query is correct

Tags: sql, ssms, bulkinsert

Good day all, I have been busy with a Query that creates a table if it doesn't exist and I'm completely happy with what I have done. Sure it could be a bit better but I'm still a newby ^^. What i do want to double check on is my update Script if the table exists then to update it from a text file. This is my script so far:

```
USE Test
GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Final') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  #TEMP ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,  [SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null
                    ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)

                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Final]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT])
                    SELECT CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME]) AS [DateStamp], [TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT]
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT [TIME] FROM [dbo].[Final] WHERE [TIME] = [TIME])
                    DROP TABLE #TEMP
        END
```

This is the Create query if it doesn't exist:

```
USE Test
GO
    IF (OBJECT_ID('Final') IS NULL and OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NULL)
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  Final ([DateStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL, [TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] date NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PRODUCT_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[OPERATION ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[CLIENT_IP ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[OBJECT    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VIEW_TYPE ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VIEW] nvarchar(max) NULL)
            CREATE TABLE  #Temp ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PRODUCT_NAME   ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[OPERATION ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[CLIENT_IP ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[OBJECT    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VIEW_TYPE ] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VIEW] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', MAXERRORS = 5, FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #Temp SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] = ''
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null 
                    ALTER TABLE #Temp ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #Temp SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)

                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Final]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[PRODUCT_NAME  ],[MODEL_NAME   ],[OPERATION    ],[CLIENT_IP    ],[OBJECT   ],[VIEW_TYPE    ],[VIEW])
                    SELECT CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME]) AS [DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[PRODUCT_NAME    ],[MODEL_NAME   ],[OPERATION    ],[CLIENT_IP    ],[OBJECT   ],[VIEW_TYPE    ],[VIEW]
                    FROM #Temp
                    DROP TABLE #Temp

                    UPDATE [dbo].[Final] SET [DateStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,(SUBSTRING([DateStamp],1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING([DateStamp],11,15)))
                    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Final] ALTER COLUMN [DateStamp] DATETIME
        END
```

Could anyone advise me if i have done it in the correct procedure and I'm a bit unsure of this part and where to add it in the update Query.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Final] SET [DateStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,(SUBSTRING([DateStamp],1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING([DateStamp],11,15)))
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Final] ALTER COLUMN [DateStamp] DATETIME
```

Could anyone advise me on the query and if it's good and if there is anything else I should do. Any advice is welcome! I'm here to learn. Thank you ^^

Comment: Run it on a test system / test data or wrap it in transaction and rollback

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something more straightforward.
I've reworked your scrip (but i didn't test, since i don't have you test.txt file)

Actually, I made thoses changes :

- Use a table variable instead of a temp table. You don't need to delete or check if it already exist. It's a variable, and will be destroyed at the end of 
  your script
- Check the existance of the table with a straightforward Select in the sys.tables table
- Replace your alter statement with convert statement. You should avoid altering table for a business rule. It could generate errors and can't be rollbacked.
- Use a transaction. If the script is raising an error, at least the table Final won't be created

  ```
  Declare @FinalTableExist bit  = 0;
  IF Exists (Select * from sys.tables where name = 'Final')
      Set @FinalTableExist = 1;

  Declare @TmpTable (
      [TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [PRODUCT_NAME   ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [MODEL_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [OPERATION ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [CLIENT_IP ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [OBJECT    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [VIEW_TYPE ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [VIEW] nvarchar(max) NULL)

  if (@FinalTableExist = 0)
  Begin
      Begin try

          CREATE TABLE  Final (
              [DateStamp] DateTime NULL, 
              [TIME] time NULL,
              [DATE] date NULL,
              [USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [PRODUCT_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [MODEL_NAME    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [OPERATION ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [CLIENT_IP ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [OBJECT    ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [VIEW_TYPE ] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              [VIEW] nvarchar(max) NULL)


              BULK INSERT @TmpTable FROM 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
              WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', MAXERRORS = 5, FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] = ''
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null 
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
              UPDATE @TmpTable SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)

              INSERT INTO [dbo].[Final](
                      [DateStamp],
                      [TIME],
                      [DATE],
                      [USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[PRODUCT_NAME  ],[MODEL_NAME   ],[OPERATION    ],[CLIENT_IP    ],[OBJECT   ],[VIEW_TYPE    ],[VIEW])
              SELECT Convert(Datetime, CONCAT([DATE],' ', [TIME])),
                     Convert(Time, [TIME]),
                     Convert(Date, [DATE]),
                      [USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[PRODUCT_NAME    ],[MODEL_NAME   ],[OPERATION    ],[CLIENT_IP    ],[OBJECT   ],[VIEW_TYPE    ],[VIEW]
              FROM @TmpTable
          End Try
          BEGIN CATCH
              SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                      ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                      ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
                      ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
                      ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
                      ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
          END CATCH;
  ```

Comment: Hi Sébastien, I got a few errors but fixed them, have 2 left. 1 is :`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '@TmpWASUserAudit'.`

the second is: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near ';'.` which is at the end.

Comment: Thx Christoph :) Mark my comment as anwser if you're agree :)